# Is it possible to run JavaScript before any image loads?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to run JavaScript before any image loads?

Is this default behavior? Dom, script, IMG load?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Javascript runs before images have loaded by default. The `window` object's `load` event fires when images have completed loading (for most clients; some versions of Safari have fired `load` before images complete), but you're in no way obligated to wait for that event to run code.

The jQuery `ready` event (as seen in another comment) fires when the DOM is assumed to be ready for complete interaction (and in some clients, the DOM is progressively ready for interaction as it is parsed). It's also not necessary, depending on what code you want to run.

- If you want to **run code that doesn't depend on the document** at all, you can run it in any script tag at any time and it will run immediately as soon as the script is downloaded and parsed.
- If you want to **run code that depends on the DOM but not on images** (or, necessarily, styles), you will want to look for a cross-browser DOM-load event simulator (similar to [this](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/domready.shtml) but not necessarily that, there are a lot of implementations out there).
- If you want to **run code when the page has finished loading**, you'll want to use the `load` event (and you'll want to use an abstraction around `window.addEventListener()` and `window.attachEvent()`, rather than assigning to `window.onload`.

Comment: Awesome. But to be clear, the linked solution does not necessarily run before images have loaded, right? I imagine the first image loads while the rest of the Dom gets loaded?

Comment: Theoretically, DOM readiness might coincide with (or lag behind) the `load` event. But if that's the case, it's moot (as you can't have safely interacted with the DOM however you see fit before the `load` event anyway).

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is by using window.onload like this :

```
<script>
function init() {
alert("");
}
window.onload = init; 
</script>
```

This is alternative to answer below because it doesn't use jQuery

You might want to consider reading [this](http://haacked.com/archive/2006/04/06/StopTheWindow.OnloadMadness.aspx)

Comment: Seriously? You can only have one onload event? I would have thought I'd found that out already

Comment: This doesn't fire until the images are loaded though.

Answer (score 0):

You could just put your script tags in the `<head></head>` and put your code outside of any function. It will be run before (and while) the browser is parsing the page.

Not useful if you need the DOM to be loaded, of course.

Very basic, and bad form, but it is an option. Just a thought.

Answer (score -1):

Just use the ready function of [jQuery](http://jquery.com/).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Your code here.
});
```

Or, for short you can just do

```
$(function(){
    // Your code here.
});
```

Comment: It's my understanding that runs when the Dom is ready. Does that necessarily mean images have not yet loaded?

A non library solution is also preferable.

Answer (score -1):

You could have the script get the images.  I had a script that resized an image, but it would flash its normal size on load.  I got around it by adding document.getElementById("theImg").src = "theImg.jpg"; *after* the resize line